# Is it safe to just implement __lt__ for a class that will be sorted?

Tags: python, sorting

Suppose instances of my ClassA will end up in a data structure and we know sorted() will be called on it.  It's someone else's code that'll call sorted() so I can't specify a sorting function but I can implement whatever methods are appropriate on ClassA.

It appears to me that

```
def __lt__(self, other):
```

is sufficient and that I don't need implement the other five or so methods (qt,eq,le,ge,ne).

Is this sufficient?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends against this practice.  I also recommend against it because it is a fragile programming style (not robust against minor code modifications):

Instead, consider using the [functools.total_ordering](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) class decorator to do the work:

```
@total_ordering
class Student:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return ((self.lastname.lower(), self.firstname.lower()) ==
                (other.lastname.lower(), other.firstname.lower()))
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return ((self.lastname.lower(), self.firstname.lower()) <
                (other.lastname.lower(), other.firstname.lower()))
```

Comment: Python's sort *is* documented as using only `__lt__()`, just for the record, but future-proofing is good. I didn't know about this one!

Comment: @kindall Did you get that from my sorting howto guide?  Please provide a link so I can edit the docs to be clearer that relying on \_\_lt\_\_ is not recommended.

Comment: Yes it is (didn't realize you wrote it!). It's under Odds and Ends: "The sort routines are guaranteed to use __lt__() when making comparisons between two objects."

Comment: Can you give an example of how \_\_lt\_\_ only would break with minor code modifications?

Comment: @Tony Yes, I can.  When the heapq module switched from \_\_le\_\_ to \_\_lt\_\_ it broke Twisted which made exactly this mistake (relying on an implementation detail and ignoring the recommended best practice).  As a consequence, we had to add adapter code in Python 2.7 that showed down heapq by a factor of ten for all the users.  In other words, yes this is a bad practice with real-world consequences.  The recommended best practice is there for a reason.  And the ``functools.total_ordering`` decorator makes it trivially easy to comply with the best practice with only a single line of code.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger I may not be understanding you. What implementation detail was Twisted relying on?

Comment: It should be even simpler. Something like `total_order_key("obj")` where `obj` is an attribute (or a list of them)

Comment: The guarantee that sorting will only use `__lt__` is also documented in PEP8 `The sort() and min() operations are guaranteed to use the < operator and the max() function uses the > operator. However, it is best to implement all six operations so that confusion doesn’t arise in other contexts.` The advice to implement all operations is also there, and worth following.