# Sort custom class without use of `key` argument?

Tags: python

You can sort an array of `myclass` by using the `key` argument to the `sorted` function:

```
sortedlist = sorted(myclasses, key=lambda obj: obj.myproperty)
```

Is there a way to define a natural ordering for our class? Perhaps some magic method so that we don't have to pass in a key each time?

e.g.,

```
class myclass:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.key1 = a
        self.key2 = b

    def __sortkey__(self):
        return self.key2
```

Or will it naturally work if we define `__le__` perhaps?

Answer (score 20):

In addition to `__cmp__`, you can also do it with the so-called "rich comparison operators" `__eq__`, `__le__`, `__lt__`, `__gt__`, and `__ge__`. Rather than defining all of them, you can use the [`functools.total_ordering`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) class decorator in 2.7+/3.1+. `__cmp__` is gone in 3.x.

Comment: Even better. `__le__` is easier to implement as I only need to return a bool.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it by overriding [`__cmp__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__)

```
class myclass:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.key1 = a
        self.key2 = b

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return cmp(self.key2, other.key2)
```

Update:
In python3, [`__cmp__` is gone](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html?highlight=__cmp__).

Use `__lt__` instead

Comment: Ah. Nice! Couldn't find it under http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted

Comment: Since Python 3, `__cmp__` is no longer supported. https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html?highlight=__cmp__

Answer (score 3):

See [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796886/is-it-safe-to-just-implement-lt-for-a-class-that-will-be-sorted).  The answer is that you can get away with just using `__lt__`, but it's better to use [`functools.total_ordering`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering).