# Comparing lists of objects with custom key

Tags: python, list, sorting

I sort some objects based on one of their attributes, using something like this:

```
sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list, key=lambda x: x.my_attr)
```

Is there any way to sort a list of lists of these objects, in the same way that Python can sort lists of lists of integers? I can overload `__cmp__(self, other)` for these objects, but this throws up difficulties in an external package. The nesting may become arbitrarily deep too, so I don't think I can just use a list comprehension.

I was wondering if there was something where I could generate lists of the `my_attr`s and link this to the corresponding lists of objects. I can't think of a nice way to do it offhand.

Comment: can you show example of your nested lists perhaps there is a better way to do it without generating lists of `my_attr`. ? Also include expected output

Comment: `[[340 N N, 338 C C], [344 C CB, 350 C CG1], [357 C C, 358 O O], [343 H HA]]`

That's an example of the first level of recursion. The objects are atoms, and what I'm trying to do is sort based on the [Cahn Ingold Prelog rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cahn%E2%80%93Ingold%E2%80%93Prelog_priority_rules#Assignment_of_priorities). It's the expansion in step number 2 that's causing the nesting, and the attribute I'm using is the atom's atomic number.

Comment: You should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31751232/edit) your question and add that.

Comment: Are you trying to sort the atoms in each list or the order of the lists that contain the atoms?

Comment: You explained what's wrong with overloading ´__cmp__´. But what's wrong with the example line you gave? Is it that you want to consider multiple attribues in the comparison? Then, instead of passing a key to sorted(), pass a comparison function, as parameter cmp.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement comparison functions on your data type and then rely on Python's sorting functions.

See similar question and answers: [Python: Sort custom class without use of `key` argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705371/python-sort-custom-class-without-use-of-key-argument)

In short, you can use `total_ordering` meta-class and implement `__eq__` and `__lt__` functions.

In your specific case, you may implement `__eq__` like this:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.my_attr == other.my_attr
```

and similarly for `__lt__`.