# Python3: why the comparison is naturally made?

Tags: python-3.x, magic-methods

In the code below, I defined '<' in the magic method `__lt__()`, which will return `True` if the first argument is less than the second one, return False otherwise.

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering  
class Currency:
    """
    One object of class Currency stores one amount of money, dollars and cents.
    """

    def __add__(self, other):
        """
        returns the result of adding self to other
        """
        total = Currency(self.dollars, self.cents)
        total.dollars = total.dollars + other.dollars
        print (other.dollars)
        total.cents = total.cents + other.cents
        print (other.cents)
        if total.cents > 100:
            total.cents = total.cents - 100
            total.dollars = total.dollars +1
        return total

    def __init__(self, dollars=0, cents=0):
        self.dollars = dollars
        self.cents =  cents

    def __str__(self):
        return "$"+str(self.dollars)+"."+str(self.cents)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.dollars==other.dollars and self.cents==other.cents    

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.dollars<other.dollars:
            return True
        elif self.dollars > other.dollars:
            return False
        else:  # dollars are equal
            return self.cents < other.cents
```

And then I called `__lt__()` in the test program with '<'. In this case, the `candyPrice`(first argument) is less than `bookPrice`(second argument), so it returned `True` as expected. And then, I compared these two values with '>' which was not predefined in `class Currency`, but it also returned `False` as expected. **So I'm wondering if it's because `__lt__()` was defined already, then the opposite expression, the '>' expression, was also implicitly defined?**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    candyPrice = Currency (1, 17)  # $1.17
    bookPrice = Currency (12, 99)  # $12.99

    print (candyPrice < bookPrice)
    print (candyPrice > bookPrice)
```

Comment: Did you test your program with arguments that have equal prices?

Comment: @Kairat Yes, I did. And I'll add it to my question. Thank you

Comment: Try putting a `print` statement in the comparison, and that'll show what's getting called. In general, *no*, `__gt__` is not defined. I think (not sure) that it could figure out that `candy > book` is the same as `book < candy` if you define something like `__rle__`. Either way, if you `decorate` your class with `@functools.total_ordering`, then it *WILL* define `__gt__` and all the other functions for you.

Comment: [read the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__): "There are no swapped-argument versions of these methods (to be used when the left argument does not support the operation but the right argument does) rather, __lt__() and __gt__() are each other’s reflection"  so if `x.__gt__(y)` is not supported it uses `y.__lt__(x)`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796886/is-it-safe-to-just-implement-lt-for-a-class-that-will-be-sorted

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: that doesn't apply, because the OP used the `@total_ordering` decorator.

Comment: I missed that.  In that case this seems like a kind of silly question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used the `@total_ordering` class decorator. This decorator explicitly adds the other methods **for you**.

From the [`@functools.total_ordering` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering):

> Given a class defining one or more rich comparison ordering methods, this class decorator supplies the rest. This simplifies the effort involved in specifying all of the possible rich comparison operations:
>
> The class must define one of `__lt__()`, `__le__()`, `__gt__()`, or `__ge__()`. In addition, the class should supply an `__eq__()` method.

So even though you did not define a `__gt__` method, the class decorator has defined one for you using your `__lt__` method, together with `__eq__`.

For example, when defining a `__lt__` method, the `__gt__()`  implementation is set to:

```
def _gt_from_lt(self, other, NotImplemented=NotImplemented):
    'Return a > b.  Computed by @total_ordering from (not a < b) and (a != b).'
    op_result = self.__lt__(other)
    if op_result is NotImplemented:
        return op_result
    return not op_result and self != other
```

So if `self < other` is false, `self != other` is used. You did not define a `__ne__` method, but you did provide a `__eq__` and the default for `__ne__` is then to return `not self.__eq__(other)`; see the [`object.__ne__()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__):

> By default, `__ne__()` delegates to `__eq__()` and inverts the result unless it is `NotImplemented`.

For your test `Currency` instances `__eq__` is not needed, `candyPrice.__gt__(bookPrice)` calls `candyPrice.__lt__(bookPrice)`, which returns true and thus `False` is returned without checking for `self != other`.