# How can I sort this list in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
def project():
    JobList = []

    class Job:
        def __init__(self, name, cycle):
            self.name = name
            self.cycle = cycle
            JobList.append(self)

    #Acquire Job Info From User

    Job_A = float(input("What is the CPU cycle for Job A in ms? "))
    A = Job("A", Job_A)
    Job_B = float(input("What is the CPU cycle for Job B in ms? "))
    B = Job("B", Job_B)
    Job_C = float(input("What is the CPU cycle for Job C in ms? "))
    C = Job("C", Job_C)
    Job_D = float(input("What is the CPU cycle for Job D in ms? "))
    D = Job("D", Job_D)
    Job_E = float(input("What is the CPU cycle for Job E in ms? "))
    E = Job("E", Job_E)

    NewList = JobList.sort(key=lambda elem: elem[0])

    print(NewList)


project()
```

I know I can use

```
NewList = sorted(JobList,key = lambda x: x.cycle)
```

and it will sort my list from least to greatest, but I am looking another another way to do it. I have tried using a few other ways to sort my list from least to greatest but I havent gotten any of them to work.

Comment: What's wrong with what you currently have?

Comment: "I am looking another another way to do it" isn't a question.  Your last line looks like the proper way to do it, what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 2):

If you define `__lt__()` on your `Job` class in a way that defines what less than means between two instances, you can then just use `.sort()` or `sorted()`. This works because python [only depends on < comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) to sort.

```
class Job:
    def __init__(self, name, cycle):
        self.name = name
        self.cycle = cycle

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.cycle < other.cycle

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Job({self.name}, {self.cycle})"

job_list = [
    Job("A", 1.5),
    Job("B", 6.5),
    Job("C", 0.3),
    Job("D", 2.9),
    Job("E", 1.8)
]

sorted(job_list)
# [Job(C, 0.3), Job(A, 1.5), Job(E, 1.8), Job(D, 2.9), Job(B, 6.5)]
```

FWIW, it is [sometimes recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8796908/3874623) to implement `__eq__()` with [`total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) as well to define all comparisons between objects. (Left if off for simplicity here since it wasn't needed)

Comment: *"The sort algorithm uses only < comparisons between items. While defining an __lt__() method will suffice for sorting, PEP 8 recommends that all six rich comparisons be implemented. This will help avoid bugs when using the same data with other ordering tools such as max() that rely on a different underlying method. Implementing all six comparisons also helps avoid confusion for mixed type comparisons which can call reflected the __gt__() method."* Source: [documentation for builtin function `sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)

Comment: Appreciate the quote @Stef, that’s why I linked to the doc. Had I implemented this, I would have had comments pointing out that the docs also say only `<` is needed. So I opted for simplicity to show the technique with links to further discussion. I clarified the last paragraph.